# Avoid Cookie-Popup on multiple different websites using selenium etc

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

I must scrape a lot of different websites. All of them ask you for accepting there cookies.
The problem is, that the source code of these "accept" buttons is unique for each website. Is there something like a generally "cookie accept"-solution? Or maybe is it possible to avoid them complete?

Comment: Every web site will have different id, class name etc for cookie button, but do you think `Accept all` will be presented on every button ?

Comment: No, i dont really think so. Some websites have `Accept all`, on others there is a button with `I understand`. Thats the problem